# Is there a way to use rxjs switchMap or similar and optionally return an observable

Tags: rxjs

I have one observable and I want to optionally return a new observable or an item based on a condition. I basically want to do this without creating an empty observable:

```
obs.switchMap(data => {
  if(data.condition) return obs2;
  return Observable.of(data);
});
```

The use case is that I go to the server to get the user and if the user has a specific role, I go back to the server to get more data to add to the user before returning it.

Comment: Where's an empty Observable in your example?

Comment: The Observable.of(data) maybe I'm using the wrong word. I just meant without needing to create a new observable for no reason.

Comment: Then no, if you use `switchMap` you have to return an Observable (or Observable-like object) in its callback.

Comment: Is there another operator that is similar that would work?

Comment: I don't think so. You could however return `[data]` and `switchMap` will iterate the array and emit its only item so it will kind of do what you want but it's a bit hacky and uncreal why you're doing this.

Comment: Why would you need to do this without using `EMPTY`?

Comment: I update the question to include my use case

Comment: Nothing wrong with your current approach.  Sometime it is even useful , you can also conditionally to pass never() empty() throw() if there's such need.